# java web service client trying to access web service through SSL - TrustManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, keystore, weblogic-10.x

I'm a web service client and I'm connecting to the web service through SSL.

It's a 2-way `SSL` and the producer has shared the certificate. I did run the InstallCert.java, got the alias and created a Keystore. 
I'm using `weblogic` application server and I have placed my Keystore in it.

Now when I run it, I'm getting an error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
                                      TrustManagerFactoryImpl is not initialized
```

Before this I could see that it is trying to load the identity certificate and the private key. But as per standards the producer isn't willing to share the private key with us.

Any suggestion on this would be of great help to me. Thanks.

Comment: What did the producer of the web service share with you? Just the certificate or a P12?

Comment: Yes, the producer has just shared the certificate.

Comment: If it is a 2 way SSL u need the P12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it. 
I added my .cer file to cacerts which is referred by the weblogic server (Using keytool import). In the keystores section, I kept the default option (Demo identity and Demo trust). In the SSL section, I went to advanced, click on the checkbox ("Use JSSE SSL"). 
It worked.

Comment: I had a local instance of Weblogic 12c and got this error for some reason after some time. I simply reentered the password for my keystore and saved, restarted the managed server and it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue connecting to a MySQL database that requires SSL to connect.

It turns out, for me, the driver version needed to be updated in order to properly-handle the trust store configuration in the JDBC URL.